# How do I find the derivative?

Tags: derivatives

How do I find the derivative of this? $3x\sqrt{1-x^3}$? So far, I got $3x\sqrt{(1-x^3)}$. But I think I am making a mistake in the next step: $3x\frac{1}{2}(1-x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \times (-3x^2)$. Is this correct? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

For this kind of problems where you just face products, quotients and powers, logarithmic differentiation make life very easy.

$$y=3 x \sqrt{1-x^3} \implies \log(y)=\log(3)+\log(x)+\frac 12 \log(1-x^3)$$ Differentiate both sides
$$\frac{y'}y=\frac 1x+\frac 12\frac{-3x^2}{1-x^3}=\frac{2-5 x^3}{2 x(1- x^3)}$$

Now
$$y'=y \times \frac {y'}y=3 x \sqrt{1-x^3}\frac{2-5 x^3}{2 x(1- x^3)}$$ Now, simplify as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple by using product rule of derivative. 
$$3\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\sqrt{1-x^3}\right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\right)\sqrt{1-x^3}+\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{1-x^3}\right)x\right)$$
$$=3\left(1\cdot \sqrt{1-x^3}+\left(-\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{1-x^3}}\right)x\right)$$
$$=\frac{3\left(-5x^3+2\right)}{2\sqrt{1-x^3}}$$